# Heroku CLI will not install on new macOS Catalina 10.15.1

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, heroku-cli

I am trying to download and install the Heroku CLI for Visual Studio Code, So I can host my python app, but I keep getting this message: "heroku (2).pkg can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software."

It might be because of the newest OS update to my imac which is macOSCatalina 10.15.1

Can anyone tell me if this is the case? and if so how long it might take for the issue to be fixed?

Or if there is any way around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Mac OS 10.14 Mojave software should be notarized, and Catalina enforces this constraint.
[Notarization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution) is for the software publisher to perform and downloaded but notarized software installers, DMGs or packages will pass the gatekeeper security check, thus not showing this error.

You should report this to Heroku and see if they have a notarized version or can produce one in the future.

In the meantime, this is a **workaround**:

1. Locate the pkg file in Finder
2. Command-click and select "Open"
3. The popup should allow you to "open anyway" or similar

**Important Disclaimer**

As annoying as it is for both developers and users, there is a (security) reason why Apple have chosen to do this. Do not circumvent unless you know what you're doing, as you could put your system at risk. I bear no responsibility for having told you how to do so.

Comment: Thank you Thomas the installation is now successful.

Comment: Awesome, well done. If it worked, it would be just as great if you would accept my answer :)

Comment: Hi sorry, this is the first time I have used Stack Overflow. I shall accept it.